# Silverlight: Remove loading message on content load without code behind?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm building a wp7 app in Silverlight. I have some content that gets loaded asynchronously, and messages that indicate that loading is not yet done. I'd like to have the loading messages disappear as soon as the content's list box is not empty. Is it possible to do this just in XAML? Something like binding the `Visibility` property to `StoryListBox.ItemsSource.IsEmpty`?

`StoryListBox` is populated by having its `ItemsSource` set to an observable collection after the data is available.

```
    <TextBox x:Name="LoadingMessage"  Text="Loading..." Grid.Row="0" />
    <ProgressBar x:Name="LoadingProgress" IsIndeterminate="True" Style="{StaticResource PerformanceProgressBar}" />

    <ListBox x:Name="StoryListBox" Grid.Row="0" />
```

**Update**: I tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
  <StackPanel x:Name="Loading" Grid.Row="0" Visibility="{Binding StoryListBox.ItemsSource.IsEmpty, Converter={StaticResource visibilityConverter}}">
            <TextBox Text="Loading..." />
            <ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True" Style="{StaticResource PerformanceProgressBar}" />
        </StackPanel>

        <ListBox x:Name="StoryListBox" Grid.Row="1" />
```

The `Loading` stack panel never collapses.

Comment: I would help if you provided more details about how ContentListBox is bound?  Is its `ItemsSource` property assigned once the content is available or is it just bound to a `ObservableCollection` or a `ICollectionView` that gets items added?  Is ContentListBox the "StoryListBox" in your xaml, can you tidy up this inconsistency??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have answered your own question. Yes, you can simply bind the Visibility (or Busy/IsBusy on a BusyIndicator control to some attribute of another control).

If the specific property you want to bind to is not a bindable property, simply bind to the other control and customise the converter to get the member property you want. If you have  specific code examples, just post them and I can post a more specific solution.

The usual problem is that the types (for visibility) are incompatible with boolean values, so you need to specifier a converter in the binding. Google for Silverlight VisibilityConvertor (they are a dime a dozen). Here is mine:

```
namespace Common.ValueConverters
{
    using System;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Data;

    public class VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is bool?)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)parameter))
                {
                    return (value as bool?).Value ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
                else
                {
                    return (value as bool?).Value ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
                }
            }
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

A use of the converter would look like:

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding ShowDualView, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}">
```

But quite frankly you are better of with a BusyIndicator control bound to an IsBusy property:

```
<Controls:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}">
```

Just put it around the controls to you want to have hidden by the busy display.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure exactly what the XAML for that would look like.

Comment: @Rosarch: I have added some Xaml examples (for use of the converter and a BusyIndicator). Cheers